# React Native navigation header background color reverts to white when back button is clicked

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have 5 screens on my app and I am doing the navigation as follows:

```
Landing screen
- Login screen
  - Admin screen
- Search screen
  - Profile
```

My problem is when I push to a screen and click the back button, the background color of the navigation header on the current pushed screen reverts back to white.

Here is my stack navigation on App.js

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
{
 Landing: { screen: Landing },
 Login: {
  screen: Login,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerLeft: (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
        onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "#a13547" }}>Back</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#cccccc",
      elevation: 0,
      shadowOpacity: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 0
    },
    headerTintColor: "#a13547"
  }),
  mode: "modal"
},
Admin: {
  screen: AdminScan,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerLeft: (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
        onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "#cccccc" }}>Back</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
    mode: "modal",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#a13547",
      elevation: 0,
      shadowOpacity: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 0
    }
  })
},
Search: {
  screen: Search,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerLeft: (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
        onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "#cccccc" }}>Back</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
    mode: "modal",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#a13547",
      elevation: 0,
      shadowOpacity: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 0
    }
  })
},
Profile: {
  screen: Profile,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    mode: "card",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#a13547",
      elevation: 0,
      shadowOpacity: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 0
    },
    headerTintColor: "#cccccc"
  })
}
}
);
```

For example I am on Landing screen initially. When I navigate on the Search screen, the header background color is set to #a13547 but when I click back, the background reverts to white before going back to the previous screen.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I managed to solve the reverting to white on back mode problem by setting the background to the whole stack navigator.

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
{
Landing: { screen: Landing },
Login: {
  screen: Login,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerLeft: (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
        onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "#a13547" }}>Back</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#cccccc",
      elevation: 0,
      shadowOpacity: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 0
    },
    headerTintColor: "#a13547"
  }),
  mode: "modal"
},
Admin: {
  screen: AdminScan,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerLeft: (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
        onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "#cccccc" }}>Back</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
    mode: "modal",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#a13547",
      elevation: 0,
      shadowOpacity: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 0
    }
  })
},
Search: {
  screen: Search,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerLeft: (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ marginLeft: 10 }}
        onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
      >
        <Text style={{ color: "#cccccc" }}>Back</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
    mode: "modal",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#a13547",
      elevation: 0,
      shadowOpacity: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 0
    }
  })
},
Profile: {
  screen: Profile,
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    mode: "card",
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "#a13547",
      elevation: 0,
      shadowOpacity: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 0
    },
    headerTintColor: "#cccccc"
  })
}
},// add background color for the whole stack
{
navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
  mode: "card",
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: "#a13547",
    elevation: 0,
    shadowOpacity: 0,
    borderBottomWidth: 0
 },
 headerTintColor: "#cccccc"
 })
 }
 );
```

My only problem now is that all the headers on the stack will be set to #a13547 but I only want that color for the Search screen and a different one for the Login screen. If anyone call help, I will gladly accept it as the answer.